# How to have person in video mask added geometry as they walk in front

Tags: video, tracking, masking

I have a video plate that I shot and have motion tracked into Blender. There is a person walking through the shot and I want to add geometry in front and behind them. However, things that should be behind them obviously aren't as they are in front of the video.

Is there a way in blender to have a mask matching the person tracked to the person so that the background geometry appears to go behind them? Or am I going to have to take this to After Effects or something and hand roto a mask and export it as a new video element and composite it?

Pretty new to all of this so may not be using the right terminology. Also assume I'm an idiot when responding and explain it to a 3rd grader. :) Thanks everyone who shares anything. Stuck on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video clip editor you can create masks and animate them with keyframes. For precise rotoscoping over video, load the video element on the Video Clip editor, create a new mask and you can animate the shape and feathering as you like.

[Overlaying an image to cover a face in a video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65007/overlaying-an-image-to-cover-a-face-in-a-video/65017#65017)

You can also use trackers and parent the points of the mask with the trackers, to ease the rotoscoping process.

[Can a mask stick to a shape in the motion tracker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24408/can-a-mask-stick-to-a-shape-in-the-motion-tracker/24410#24410)

Then you can use those masks in the compositor with a mask node that uses those masks to combine other images.
You don't need to use AfterFX.

[How to draw a Rotoshape (mask) in the Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134999/how-to-draw-a-rotoshape-mask-in-the-compositor/135005#135005)

To work with geometry you can check this link as well:
[Use masks as part of materials in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102342/use-masks-as-part-of-materials-in-cycles)