# How to mask out a object in motion tracked shot to put people behind things?

Tags: tracking

[image]

I want to put the girl behind the cup. How can i mask the foot of the girl? This is a motion tracked shot that moves so it doesn't just stay still.

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the answer. what you need to do is build the object you want to mask and then put it as in the background group and it will work

Comment: you don't have to have more geometry, you can crate masks: read https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/183108/92768 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space