# Partially obscuring a mesh for a video composite

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am compositing a model into a video, in which a mesh circles around an element that is depicted in the video.

Since there is a little bit of movement, it would be better to block the obscured half with an invisible object than to just cut the mesh, but I am not finding a way to do this elegantly.

Is there a way to approach the problem this way? An object that basically makes anything behind its silhouette transparent? Or is there a better way to approach?

Comment: Two basic ways to do it, one with a mesh that uses a holdout material, effectively creating an alpha channel. Or with a mask that you can use in the compositor. The second option can also be used in conjunction with trackers to automate motion, as in rotoscoping.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @susu

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/how-to-have-person-in-video-mask-added-geometry-as-they-walk-in-front/183108#183108